# How can I extract the text from the html in a specific places?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

The html content is long I will show only part of it:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="21" id="live"><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/live.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#E5E6E7> <EMBED src="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/live.swf"quality=high bgcolor=#E5E6E7  WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="21" NAME="live"TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED></OBJECT>                                                 
</td></tr><tr><td colspan=100% background="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/dots.jpg" height=2></td></tr><tr height=15><td colspan=100%></td></tr><tr><td colspan=100%><LINK title="OneStyle" href="../../css/One5.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><table dir=rtl width=100% height="24" bgcolor=#BFBFBF cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr width=100% class=TVChannelBar valign=baseline align=right><td align=right valign=bottom><img id="_ctl0_Main_TVUI1_rptDvs__ctl0_rptPrograms__ctl4__ctl1_imgChannel" src="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/channels/shabatsoccer.jpg" alt="ספורט 1" border="0" style="height:17px;" /></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr height=5><td colspan=100%></td></tr><tr class=TVProgramsTableFont height=21><td dir="rtl" width=50 align=left>                                      <nobr>
14:35&nbsp;</nobr></td><td align=center width=320>
כדורגל - גביע אנגלי, וויקום נגד אסטון וילה</font>                                           
</td><td width=80 align=center>                                                                          <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="21" id="live"><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/live.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#E5E6E7> <EMBED src="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/live.swf"quality=high bgcolor=#E5E6E7  WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="21" NAME="live"TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED></OBJECT>                                                    
</td></tr><tr><td colspan=100% background="http://images.one.co.il/images/new/tv/dots.jpg" height=2></td></tr><tr class=TVProgramsTableFont height=21><td dir="rtl" width=50 align=left>                                         <nobr>
16:45&nbsp;</nobr></td><td align=center width=320>
כדורגל ליגת ווינר - בני יהודה - הפועל ת"א</font>                                            
</td><td width=80 align=center>
```

And what i want to extract in this example is this both lines in this case in hebrew:

כדורגל - גביע אנגלי, וויקום נגד אסטון וילה

And

כדורגל ליגת ווינר - בני יהודה - הפועל ת"א

Maybe somehow using the OBJECT classid ?
Anyway this is the lines I want to extract from the html.
This is the whole page view-source link

[view-source](http://view-source:http://www.one.co.il/cat/extra/tvform.aspx)

And this is the link for the original page:

[Original page](http://www.one.co.il/cat/extra/tvform.aspx)

What I want to do in the original page if it was possible to extract the whole table as it is with colors and anything and create and save a simple image of it on the hard disk.

This is a screenshot of the original page and what I want to extract:

[image: Screenshot of what to extract as image]

So two things I would like to know if it's possible to do:

1. To extract as text each line as I mentioned above in this case the lines in hebrew. So I will have a List of all lines.
2. To save the table as in the screenshot as image I couldn't take a screenshot of all the table since some of that I needed to scroll down to see but maybe it's possible to save all the table as image.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to manipulate the retrieved page somehow, you might want to try some php DOM parser. I find PHP Simple [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) very easy to use.